# Rails JSON url encoding does not parse .json/.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, url-parameters, applicationcontroller

I have the following rails route

```
resources :apps do
  post "name/:text/,
     :on => :member, :action => :register, :as => :register,
     :text => /[^\/]+/

end
```

The url that hits it in json format is the following:

```
curl -v -s -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '' -X POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/apps/1/name/hello.json
```

When my rails controller receives the request above, it can't see that the `.json` at the end of the url is part of the url encoding/extension and not part of hello. It sees the params as the following:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1", "text"=>"hello.json"}
```

instead of having `"text" => "hello"`.

I also have `respond_to :json` in my AppsController.

Any idea why this happens? and how to make rails parse the `.json` out?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You didn't include the format part in your route, i.e: `/path/to(.:format)`
- I'm not really sure what your regex does, but you may want to review it

I tried the following and it seems to work fine:

```
resources :apps do
  post "name/:text(.:format)",
     :on => :member, :action => :register, :as => :register,
     :text => /[a-z]+/

end
```

Comment: So my text could have any . or - or any other character in it. the (.:format) didn't work for me, but thanks for pointing me to :format, I did `:format => true` in my routes and it did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing `:format => true` in the route fixed this issue for me. Looks like adding `(.:format)` worked for @H-man.

Also this is the reference for :format http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html#route-globbing

However setting `:format => true` forces the format to be always presented, and `:format => false` pretty much ignores the format, which is what's happening now.

I realized the issue was with my regex `/[^\/]+/` matches everything besides `/` which matches .json as well.